# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, json, django, encoding, jinja2

So, as title of the questions says, I have a problem with encoding/decoding of strings.

I am using:
**python 2.7 | django 1.11 | jinja2 2.8**

Basically, I am retrieving some data from data base, I serialize it, set cache on it, then get the cache, deserialize it and rendering it to the template.

**Problem:**

I have first names and last names of persons that have characters like "ă" in the names.
I serialize using json.dumps.

A sample of serialized dictionary looks like (I have 10 like this):

```
active_agents = User.region_objects.get_active_agents()
agents_by_commission_last_month = active_agents.values(....
                                                          "first_name", "last_name").order_by(
        '-total_paid_transaction_value_last_month')
```

Then, when I set the cache I do it like:

```
for key, value in context.items():
   ......
   value = json.dumps(list(value), default=str, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')
```

, where value is the list of dictionaries returned by `.values()` from the aforementioned code and key is `region_agents_by_commission_last_month` (like the variable from the previous code)

Now, I have to get the cache. So I am doing the same process, but reversed.

```
serialized_keys = ['agencies_by_commission_last_month',
                       'region_agents_by_commission_last_month', 'region_agents_by_commission_last_12_months',
                       'region_agents_by_commission_last_30_days',
                       'agencies_by_commission_last_year',
                       'agencies_by_commission_last_12_months',
                       'agencies_by_commission_last_30_days',
                       'region_agents_by_commission_last_year',
                       'agency',
                       'for_agent']
    context = {}

    for key, value in region_ranking_cache.items():
        if key in serialized_keys:
            objects = json.loads(value, object_hook=_decode_dict)
            for serilized_dict in objects:
                ....
                 d['full_name'] = d['first_name'] + " " + d['last_name']
                 full_name = d['full_name'].decode('utf-8').encode('utf-8')
                 d['full_name'] = full_name
                 print(d['full_name'])
                ....
```

where _decode_dict for object_hook looks like:

The result from print: Cătălin Pintea , which is ok.
But in the dictionary I render:  `'full_name': 'C\xc4\x83t\xc4\x83lin Pintea',`

```
def _decode_list(data):
    rv = []
    for item in data:
        if isinstance(item, unicode):
            item = item.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            item = _decode_list(item)
        elif isinstance(item, dict):
            item = _decode_dict(item)
        rv.append(item)
    return rv


def _decode_dict(data):
    rv = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(key, unicode):
            key = key.encode('utf-8')
        if isinstance(value, unicode):
            value = value.encode('utf-8')
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            value = _decode_list(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            value = _decode_dict(value)
        rv[key] = value
    return rv
```

Basically, I use this object hook function in order to encode() to utf-8 all keys and value when `json.loads`.

This is how I avoided this error to be thrown in `views.py`.

**Error**

Somewhere on template, I am using:

`<td>{{ agent.full_name }}</td>`

And agent.full_name comes from : `'full_name': 'C\xc4\x83t\xc4\x83lin Pintea',`

**Traceback**

```
Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in inner
  185.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/app/crmrebs/utils/__init__.py" in wrapper
  255.             return http_response_class(t.render(output, request))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django_jinja/backend.py" in render
  106.         return mark_safe(self.template.render(context))

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py" in render
  989.         return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/jinja2/environment.py" in handle_exception
  754.         reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/app/crmrebs/jinja2/ranking/dashboard_ranking.html" in top-level template code
  1. {% extends "base.html" %}

File "/app/crmrebs/jinja2/base.html" in top-level template code
  1. {% extends "base_stripped.html" %}

File "/app/crmrebs/jinja2/base_stripped.html" in top-level template code
  94.           {% block content %}

File "/app/crmrebs/jinja2/ranking/dashboard_ranking.html" in block "content"
  83.           {% include "dashboard/region_ranking.html" %}

File "/app/crmrebs/jinja2/dashboard/region_ranking.html" in top-level template code
  41.         {% include "dashboard/_agent_ranking_row_month.html" %}

File "/app/crmrebs/jinja2/dashboard/_agent_ranking_row_month.html" in top-level template code
  2.   <td>{{ agent.full_name }}</td>

Exception Type: UnicodeDecodeError at /ranking
Exception Value: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And this is from where the error comes. I tried other things, but I guess it is a limitation of python 2.7. I usually use python 3.9, but for this project I have to use 2.7.
I tried other answers around here but nothing really helped.

Can anybody help me to serialize this dictionary properly and how can I avoid this mess?

I hope I made myself clear.

Have a nice day everyone !

Comment: You haven't provided a traceback, but I can see one error. `d['first_name'] + " " + d['last_name']` concatenates a `unicode` to a string `" "`. That forces coercion to ascii, which fails. Do `d['first_name'] + u" " + d['last_name']`. There may be similar other errors and without the traceback it's hard to be sure.

Comment: Are you using python2.7 and django 1.11 on a webserver? Remember that both of them have no more security updates since years. Consider your webserver and entire database as compromised (and from my experience, this is very probable).

Comment: @BoarGules I provided the entire Traceback ! 
I will check to see whether that is the problem.
So basically d['first_name'] is already encoded from here ```value = value.encode('utf-8')``` from the _decode_dict function.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I am working on an old project. Bear with me.

Comment: @BoarGules also, If I isolate the function and call it from ```shell```, the way that you said, I get: ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/app/agencies/utils.py", line 267, in get_region_agency_cache
    d['full_name'] = d['first_name'] + u" " + d['last_name']
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to solve my issue.

1. I figured out that `active_agents.values(...."first_name", "last_name").order_by('-total_paid_transaction_value_last_month')`
   retrieved a dictionary where its key and values were already in unicode (bacause of the way it was configured in models.py, **django 1.11** and **python2.7**. So, the process of serializing was just fine.
   It is indeed true that the final result that went to template was looking like `’C\xc4\x83t\xc4\x83lin'`. The error came from /xc4/.
2. In order to fix it on template, I just did this:
   **{{ agent.full_name.decode("utf-8") }}**, which gave me the right result: `Cătălin Pintea`

Thanks @BoarGules. It was true that `d['last_name']` and `d['first_name']` were in unicode. So when I did the concatenation, I had to add `u" "`.